# Jquery find next (specified) element not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find the next div using Jquery. Here is the code:

```
$('.menu-item').hover(function() {
  $(this).stop(true, true).addClass("menu-item-hover", 300);
  $(this).next('div').stop(true, true).fadeIn(300);
}, function() {
  $(this).stop(true, true).removeClass("menu-item-hover", 300);
  $(this).next('div').stop(true, true).fadeOut(300);
});


<a href="media.html"><div class="menu-item"><h1>Media</h1></div></a>
<div id="tooltip-media">Sights and sounds from Cambodia</div>

<a href="about.html"><div class="menu-item"><h1>About</h1></div></a>
<div id="tooltip-about">Who in the world is the Phillips Family?</div>
```

Simple. The `toolip-*` divs are hidden in css. I want the next one in the code to show on hover of the `menu-item`. I have checked other questions and none of them work for my case. I am using both Jquery and Jquery UI. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle for your example.

Comment: .next() applies to siblings. You select '.menu-item' but these are nested inside an 'a' element meaning they have no siblings.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. Got it working. Didn't realize the function of `next()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$(this).parent().next('div').stop(true, true).fadeIn(300);
```

in your example , you are trying to find next `div` but it is not sibiling of menu item.
that only it did not work. traverse to parent and find next `div` it will work.

[parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) , [next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/)

Comment: @jAndy:dude i followed author example.I wrote `query` based on example it will work.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `.next()` only grabs the immediate *next sibling*, it won't search through all sibilings. In order to do that, you would need to invoke `.nextAll('div')`. But even this function would not help you here, because that `<div>` nodes you are looking for are not contained by the same *parent element*.

You should go like

```
$( this ).parent().next( 'div[id^=tooltip]' ).stop( true, true ).fadeOut( 300 );
```

Reference: [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/), [`.nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/)